# Paypal's Subscription MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS setting in Express Checkout or Basic HTML Code

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

We are trying to implement subscription on our website using Paypal's subscription feature. What we want is to let Paypal do the recurring process even if the first payment fails until we or the subscribed user manually cancel the subscription profile.

From what I read here 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/ECDGRecurringPayments/#id086520F027U

If we set the  MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS variable to zero it means Paypal will still keep continuing the recurring process even if the payment fails.
However to specify the variable we have to use NVP/SOAP API.

Can we achieve the same thing using the basic HTML Code specified in the payment form ?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> <!-- billing cycle unit=month -->
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> <!-- billing cycle length -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- recurring=yes -->
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="0"> <!-- reattempt=no -->
{{--End of recurring variables--}}
```

I could not find the option here 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, and what's even worse is the parameter you mentioned for the NVP/SOAP API gets ignored.

No matter what you set that paramter to PayPal follows the same routine, which is this...

If a scheduled payment fails it will re-attempt in 5 days.  If there are three re-attempts that each fail the profile will be "suspended due to max failed payments."

IPNs would be triggered for each failed attempt as well as for the suspension of a profile, so it's recommended to get an IPN solution setup and working if you do go that route.

What's strange, too, is that sometimes a profile will become suspended after failing three re-attempts as explained, but then if you "collect outstanding balance" using the same billing details provided for the subscription it will process successfully, and then you can re-activate the subscription profile.

Honestly, if I had it to do over again with my own system I would probably not use PayPal's recurring payments API.  Instead I would use billing agreements and reference transactions so that I can build my own recurring system and process payments whenever I need for any amount I need.  If you're just getting started I would recommend the same for you.

Comment: So for that being said. I can't even update the parameter MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS for a specific subscription id even using NVP/SOAP API after the subscription profile is created using the express checkout HTML form because no matter how I try it will get ignored by Paypal ?

Comment: First of all, "subscriptions" and "recurring payments" are different products in PayPal.  Subscriptions work with Payments Standard, which are the HTML buttons you're referring to.  There is no API access to update these or manage them in any way.  Recurring Payments is when you create profiles using the APIs, and then you would have access to update, suspend, activate, cancel, etc. via the API.

Comment: I thought they were the same things because as I read the documentation a subscription will also result to recurring payments. So for my case, can I just implement standard payment upon user signing up for the first month and then after the payment is received I will create the recurring payments for the user and let Paypal bill the user starting the second month using NVP/SOAP API. Is that possible ?

Comment: The standard payment I mean here is not a subscription button but a one time payment probably using cart because user can subscribe to several services at once.

Comment: The end result is the same...a subscription profile.  It's just a matter of terminology that PayPal uses for HTML buttons vs. API calls.  The former being called "Subscriptions" and the latter being called "Recurring Payments".  You will not be able to create a profile with a standard HTML button and then use APIs for that profile after that.  You would have to create it with the Recurring Payments API to begin with.

Comment: To take an initial payment that is not a subscription / recurring profile, and then process future payments against that would require billing agreement / reference transactions, which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I think I finally get your point because we cannot just ask Paypal bill the customer/user periodically without asking for their agreement if we ever create the Recurring Payments using API call. Anyway I appreciate your response and thank you very much for so much insight. I will consult this thing with my team.